# gwt 2.8.0 jsinterop export not working

Tags: gwt

Reviewing this document:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/10fmlEYIHcyead_4R1S5wKGs1t2I7Fnp_PaNaa7XTEk0/edit

Exporting a java class and preserving its method names in javascript, should be as easy as annotating a class, and does not seem to work.

Here are the steps:

Create a new GWT Web Application in Eclipse. Project name="jsinterop" , package="com.example.jsinterop", use GWT2.8.0 and uncheck App Engine and click finish.

Create new class

```html
package com.example.jsinterop.client;

import jsinterop.annotations.*;

@JsType
public class Foo {
  public int x;
  public int y;

  public int sum() {
    return x + y;
  }
}
```

add JSNI method to Entry point class

```html
public static native int callfoo() /*-{
  var foo = new com.example.jsinterop.client.Foo();
  foo.x = 1;
  foo.y = 2;

  return foo.sum();

  }-*/;
```

call this method in the Entry point.

```html
callfoo();
```

Running the application will produce a javascript error like this in Chrome:

```html
Uncaught ReferenceError: com is not defined
    at rb_g$ (Jsinterop.java:155)
    at qb_g$.sb_g$ [as onModuleLoad_0_g$] (Jsinterop.java:77)
    at Array.cyc_g$ (com_00046example_00046jsinterop_00046Jsinterop__EntryMethodHolder.java:3)
    at initializeModules_0_g$ (ModuleUtils.java:44)
    at MJ_g$ (Impl.java:239)
    at PJ_g$ (Impl.java:298)
    at Impl.java:77
    at vxc_g$ (ModuleUtils.java:55)
    at StringHashCache.java:23
```

How can I get this simple implementation to work? Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `$wnd.com.example.jsinterop.client.Foo();`

Comment: @Tobika new error message: Cannot read property 'example' of undefined

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$wnd.@com.example.jsinterop.client::Foo()`? `instance.@class-name::method`. I think you can omit instance, as this is a constructor.

Comment: @Adam I get an error within the JSNI block.

Comment: @user1465576 Did you pass `--generateJsInteropExports` to the compiler and/or superdevmode?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer that was it! Thank you very much sir!! The sample app above did not work JSNI, but my previous implementation works perfectly!

Comment: Posted as answer, with additional details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is exported by default, you have to ask for it by passing `--generateJsInteropExports` to GWT (compiler or superdevmode).

Note that the next version of GWT 2.x will allow you to whitelist packages/classes to export vs the current all-or-nothing.

Comment: Thanks again. Works like a charm!

Comment: Note: When compiling from Eclipse, you must open the "Advanced" section in the compile dialog and add the option. It is spelled `-generateJsInteropExports` (with only one dash)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@JsType` with a specific namespace like for example:

```
@JsType(namespace = JsPackage.GLOBAL)
class Foo{...}
```

should make Foo available in JS without "`com.example.jsinterop.client.`"

agree ?

and consider the use of `@JsMethod(isNative = true, namespace = JsPackage.GLOBAL)` as a replacement of JSNI.

Comment: Thanks @Vincent for the feedback, I had tried this but as Thomas Boyer suggested, I needed to have -generateJsInteropExports added to my GWT compiler options.